# Run multiple processors for a single file type in eslint

Tags: eslint

I have 2 ESLINT custom plugins which has processor each for "js" file types. one processor updates the error messages to warnings, and the other processor filters the messages, when I add these 2 plugins to the eslint config, one plugin processor overrides the other. Is there any way where we can chain the processors for the given file type?